# Expression in With statement becomes Nothing in lambda expression in Task

Tags: vb.net, lambda, task

I have discovered that referencing a member variable in a lambda expression executed in a Task throws a `NullReferenceException` when accessing it using the `With` statement.

For example I expect the following code to print two lines on the console. The first one accesses the `SomeString` member via `obj.SomeString` while the second one uses the `With` statement and accesses the member via `.SomeString`. I expected both options to be equivalent but the second one throws an exception.

```
Class Foo
    Public SomeString As String
End Class

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim obj As New Foo With {.SomeString = "Hello World"}

        With obj
            Task.Factory.StartNew(
                Sub()
                    Console.WriteLine("1:" + obj.SomeString) ' works
                    Console.WriteLine("2:" + .SomeString) ' NullReferenceException here
                End Sub)
        End With

        Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub

End Module
```

When I move the `Console.ReadKey()` statement into the `With` statement, the code works.

I fixed the actual code by not using the `With` statement but I still don't know what concept I'm missing here. Why can I access members of the `obj` variable in the lambda expression but not the members of the `With` expression? It has not been garbage collected because I can still see it in the debugger when the exception is thrown. The expression seems to go out of scope (or something like that) but why doesn't the compiler just do what I expect and treats it the same as `obj`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the voodoo that the VB compiler does to support the `With` block and lambda expressions.  If you look at your code through a decompiler like Redgate's Reflector, your code gets converted into something like the code below except that I renamed the variables to ones supported by VB;  they can be quite long and include characters that are invalid for VB variable names

```
<STAThread> _
Public Shared Sub Main()
     Dim var1 As New GeneratedClass1
     Dim foo As New Foo With {.SomeString = "Hello World"}
     var1.objVar = foo

     Dim var2 As New GeneratedClass1.GeneratedClass2 With {.var2 = var1, .theWithVariable = var1.objVar}
     Task.Factory.StartNew(New Action(AddressOf var2._Lambda___1))
     var2.theWithVariable = Nothing
     Console.ReadKey()
End Sub

<CompilerGenerated> _
Friend Class GeneratedClass1
     ' Methods
     <DebuggerNonUserCode> _
     Public Sub New()
     End Sub

     <DebuggerNonUserCode> _
     Public Sub New(ByVal other As GeneratedClass1)
          If (Not other Is Nothing) Then
                Me.objVar = other.objVar
          End If
     End Sub


     ' Fields
     Public objVar As Foo

     ' Nested Types
     <CompilerGenerated> _
     Friend Class GeneratedClass2
          ' Methods
          <DebuggerNonUserCode> _
          Public Sub New()
          End Sub

          <DebuggerNonUserCode> _
          Public Sub New(ByVal other As GeneratedClass2)
                If (Not other Is Nothing) Then
                     Me.theWithVariable = other.theWithVariable
                End If
          End Sub

          <CompilerGenerated> _
          Public Sub _Lambda___1()
                Console.WriteLine(("1:" & Me.var2.objVar.SomeString))
                Console.WriteLine(("2:" & Me.theWithVariable.SomeString))
          End Sub


          ' Fields
          Public theWithVariable As Foo
          Public var2 As GeneratedClass1
     End Class
End Class
```

You can see that the compiler creates a class that holds a reference to the `With` variable and the method of the lambda expression.  As soon as the `With` variable is out of scope it is set to `Nothing` and hence the null reference expression when task executes.